# Is the genus of the complete graph on $n$ vertices the smallest genus among graphs with the same chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, extremal-graph-theory

If $K_n$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices and $G$ is a graph with chromatic number $n$
then how can we show that $\gamma(K_n)\leq \gamma(G)$ is not always true where $\gamma(x)$ is the genus of a graph.
The sequence of the chromatic number of a surface of genus $n$ is [A000934](https://oeis.org/A000934)
while the genus of the complete graph is here [A000933](https://oeis.org/A000933) which becomes much larger than the Heawood sequence.
Is this correct?

Comment: Probably not trivial. If you prove it for $n=5$ then you have proved the four color theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false.
The sequence of the chromatic number of a surface of genus $n$ is [A000934](https://oeis.org/A000934)
while the genus of the complete graph is here [A000933](https://oeis.org/A000933) which becomes much larger than the Heawood sequence disproving the claim.